# Evaluate a Spring value by another spring value with Spel

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a property from *application.properties*

```
housekeeping.shortInterval=true
```

and I want to evaluate a value in my java code dependent on this:

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{housekeeping.shortInterval == true ? 60000 : 3600000*24}")
    public int doHousekeeping()
    {...}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

**Second question**: What is the simpliest way to write a test to test the output of this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of your first question:

You need to enclose your property between `${` and `}` as shown in below example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{${housekeeping.shortInterval} == true ? 60000 : 3600000*24}")
```

I have tested it on my computer its working as expected.

Answer of your second question:

Please see below example for testing `CRON` in Spring Boot. Modify your scheduler method to store `CRON` value-

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Component
@Log4j2
public class ScheduleTask {
    @Value("${housekeeping.shortInterval}")
    private boolean shortInterval;
    private long cronValue;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{${housekeeping.shortInterval} == true ? 60000 : 3600000*24}")
    public void scheduleTask() {
        this.cronValue = ((shortInterval == true) ? 60000 : 3600000 * 24);
        log.info("Executed at {}", LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public long getCronValue() {
        return this.cronValue;
    }
}
```

Check `CRON` value while testing:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class ScheduledTaskTest {

    @Autowired
    ScheduleTask task;

    @Test
    public void scheduleTask_Cron_Test() {
        //Test CRON value
        assertEquals(task.getCronValue(), 60000l);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is really helpful. Thanks!
One more question about testing: is there a simple way of testing that the evaluated fixed rate string becomes the expected result. For me that test would be sufficient and it would be simpler and faster than testing the scheduled task itsself

Comment: Hi @ChristofNasahl, I have updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for